# Drive letter for USB device and HDD devices in Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, kernel

How the drive letter is assigned to USB/HDD drives? I meant in the code level. I looked at the code and noticed that the `gendisk struct` having the disk_name. that gives `sda/sdb/sdc....etc`. But if the disk is detected as `sda1, sdc1...`then where these names can be get form the structures/code?

Answer (score 1):

sda/sdb, etc are the block device representing the entire drive.  When the drive is partitioned, you will see the sda1, sdc1, etc.  These block devices are used to access just that partition.

I'm not familiar with the code specifically, but hopefully this will help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

One useful investigation starting point code-wise would be function `disk_name()`, defined in *`block/partition-generic.c`*:

```
  /*
   * disk_name() is used by partition check code and the genhd driver.
   * It formats the devicename of the indicated disk into
   * the supplied buffer (of size at least 32), and returns
   * a pointer to that same buffer (for convenience).
   */

  char *disk_name(struct gendisk *hd, int partno, char *buf)
  {
          if (!partno)
                  snprintf(buf, BDEVNAME_SIZE, "%s", hd->disk_name);
          else if (isdigit(hd->disk_name[strlen(hd->disk_name)-1]))
                  snprintf(buf, BDEVNAME_SIZE, "%sp%d", hd->disk_name, partno);
          else
                  snprintf(buf, BDEVNAME_SIZE, "%s%d", hd->disk_name, partno);

          return buf;
  }
```